# How much to charge for a project involving only editing the texts of all the product packages for a skincare line?

Tags: freelance, packaging

The company I primary freelance for right now wants to give me another project involving editing all of their products' packages (total of 20 products labels and outside packagings.) I will only need to edit the texts and nothing about the design. I am still relatively new in the field. I also have a personal connection with them, thus making them more willing to provide me work. And in addition, it is still a small brand even though they have been on the Red Carpet and in the Emmy Awards before. Besides within the US, the brand also will be distributed to European countries, China, US, Turkey, and Taiwan. On top of that, I might have to recreate the same packages if the original designer would not give us the original .ai files to work with. They are asking for a flat fee with some flexibility.

With all of the above mentioned, I am wondering what could the fee range be for this sort of job as a beginner? (From my understanding and google research, I realize that I might have to give both a flat fee and an hourly fee.)

+Just found out that they will likely have pdf files for providing feedbacks me to edit the text from. So the task seems to be relatively easily IF all I would end up doing is simply editing the texts.

*Thank you Scott and Yisela for providing feedbacks.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "standard" fee.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to GD.SE! Because rates vary depending on country and such, I suggest you edit your question to something like "How much [less] should I charge if I am new to the field?" or something of the kind. Unfortunately questions that ask for quotes don't usually get many answers, because of how different pricing is for everyone.

Comment: Realize that just because something is a PDF, there is *no way* of telling if it contains live text, vector outlines of text, or raster images of text without examining the PDF further. Any client who tells me "we'll give it to you as a PDF." *always* gets met with more questions.

Comment: @DumbNic Thank you for helping me see some other viewpoints regarding the question I posted. I will edit my future questions accordingly. I've read the article you mentioned, and it is helpful. However, I am simply wondering if anyone has the same experience before doing this sort of project. And what they ended up doing to figure out their quote. Opinion and cultural based viewpoints (abstract) are what I am seeking, not necessarily an exact answer (concrete). Any thought that pops in the mind helps.

Comment: There's no way anyone here is going to be able to help you with *your* pricing Anniesub100. There are just too many variables - *your* experience, *your* region, *your* direct competition, *your* clients -- all these vary wildly from person to person and are all factors in determining pricing. If you are looking for dollar values, the chances are pretty slim you'll get them here.